# Why doesn't document.querySelector() function work with html5 code?

Tags: javascript, variables, browser

**Problem:**

The canvas variable in my javascript does not appear to be detecting the canvas tag in my html document and I'm unable to detect the source of the problem.

**Information:**

I have the following code:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
console.log(canvas);
```

And ..

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
      <script src="./code.js"></script>
      <title>Canvas Resize</title>
   </head><!-- head -->
   <body>
     <canvas></canvas>
   </body><!-- body -->
</html><!-- html -->
```

And ..

```
canvas {

  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

- everything was tested with a " console.log("Hello World"); " in the js file and a " * { backgroud-color: blue; } " prior to proceeding with the code that is seen above.
- Save and refresh have been applied faithfully

I have also done a test in which I replaced the variable's rvalue with a string constant. The value set to the variable was then displayed in the console of two browsers (Chrome and Firefox) - whereas null was rendered with the original rvalue code (ie: with " document.querySelector('canvas'); " as the rvalue).

**Request:**

Is anyone able to detect what is going wrong here?  What am I missing?

- A detailed description of the problem (with pictures) can also be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5BIl.jpg

Comment: Your script is in the `<head>` tag, which means it is run before the remainder of the html is parsed. So at the time the javascript executes, there is no canvas element yet.

Comment: Thank you I wan't aware it made a difference (just starting to learn this).

Comment: The  <script src="./code.js"></script>  was placed just above the closing  </head>  tag and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Give the canvas a class and query it using `document.getElementByClassName( Canvas Class Name)`and run it through you console. If that doesn't work, then place the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the `<body>` tag to enable the browser load all the DOM objects before running your js code.